# Is it possible to have one TinyMCE Editor Bar for two Textareas?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, textarea

I have two textarea in my page that receive same type of contents (two for two portion of text).
Can I have one TinyMCE editor bar that work on focused textarea? How?

thanks

Comment: Yeah, good question. In CKEditor that's possible. Not sure about TinyMCE but I would like to find out too.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible, because all actions linked with the toolbar are bound to one editor.

Comment: Do you know if it is still not possible? They now have `inline` and `fixed_toolbar_container` in v4 but editor is doubled in `fixed_toolbar_container` when I provide multiple editable areas in `selector` option. I'm wondering if this can be fixed.

Comment: i am not into tinymce 4 much yet, but it might be possible now